# Como colocar mais de um pickerView em apenas uma ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple

Estou tentando montar uma View que pegue os dados do usuário, como altura, peso e idade, usando PickerViews.

Não está me retornando nenhum erro, porém quando executo, as pickerViews ficam apenas com uma interrogação, conforme a foto. 
No print, está me retornando o número correto da [row], porém na tela não.
Segue abaixo parte do código:

```
class IMCViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{

    let arrayAnos : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
    let arrayAltura: [Int] = [50, 51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60]
    let arrayPeso: [Int] = [30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52]


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pickerViewPeso.delegate = self
        self.pickerViewPeso.dataSource = self

        self.pickerViewAltura.delegate = self
        self.pickerViewAltura.dataSource = self

        self.pickerViewIdade.delegate = self
        self.pickerViewIdade.dataSource = self




  // MARK: - Métodos de UIPickerViewDataSource

    // Método que define a quantidade de components (colunas) do pickerView
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        if pickerView == pickerViewAltura {
      //      return arrayAltura.count
        return 1
        }
        else if pickerView == pickerViewPeso {
        return 1

        } else {
        return 1
        }
    }

    // Método que define a quantidade de linhas para cada component
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView == pickerViewAltura
        {
            return self.arrayAltura.count
        }
        else if pickerView == pickerViewPeso
        {
            return self.arrayPeso.count
        }
        else
        {
            return self.arrayAnos.count
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Métodos de UIPickerViewDelegate

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int! {
                if pickerView == pickerViewPeso {
                return self.arrayPeso[row]
            }
                if pickerView == pickerViewAltura {
                return self.arrayAltura[row]
            }
                else{

                return self.arrayAnos[row]
            }
            }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView == pickerViewPeso {
        print("Peso Selecionada: \(row)")
           pesoUsuario = arrayPeso[row]
           print ("O peso do usuário é: \(pesoUsuario)")
        }
        else if pickerView == pickerViewAltura {
        print("Altura Selecionada: \(row)")
        alturaUsuario = arrayAltura[row]
            print ("Altura do usuário: \(alturaUsuario)")
        }
        else{
        print("Idade Selecionada: \(row.description)")
            idadeUsuario = arrayAnos[row]
            print ("Idade do usuário:\(idadeUsuario)")
        }
    }
    }
```

Podem me ajudar? 
Desde já mto obrigado!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu sou novo nesse negocio de swift...E também estou apanhando para
montar um pickerview. Peguei o seu código e rodei...
Realmente aconteceu o que você demonstrou.
Então eu mudei os arrays para String

```
let arrayAnos : [String] = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"]
let arrayAltura: [String] = ["50", "51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60"]
let arrayPeso: [String] = ["30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52"]
```

e mudei o retorno da função

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int!
```

para

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
```

Ai tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Valeu Ricardo!
Realmente desse jeito funcionou também!
Porém consegui de uma outra forma rs

Eu apenas converti o resultado, pq estava retornando um Inteiro no método, porém a função titleForRow retorna apenas Strings e mantive meu array com inteiros, pois facilitaria em alguns cálculos que preciso fazer com os dados, então apenas converti o resultado para String conforme abaixo:

Muito obrigado, infelizmente sou novo no StackOverflow e não consigo contabilizar meu voto em sua resposta :/

//Função que atribui os títulos para cada row do pickerView
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

```
            if pickerView == pickerViewPeso {

                return String("\(arrayPeso[row]) Kg")
        }
                if pickerView == pickerViewAltura {
                return String("\(arrayAltura[row]) Cm")

                }else{
                if pickerView == pickerViewIdade && arrayAnos[row] == 1 {
                    return String ("\(arrayAnos[row]) ano")
                }else{
                    return String("\(arrayAnos[row]) anos")

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade `tag` e usar `switch` ou `if` e `else` para distinguir eles.

```
PickerView.tag = 1
```

E não tem necessidade de você usar `String` para converter.